# Multi-language debuggers

Tags: java, c++, debugging, ide

Some may remember old debuggers like Borland Turbo Debugger where your could seamlessly debug programs written in multiple languages like Pascal, C and Assembler. Nothing like that exists today for languages like Java and C++. I understand that the JVM and C++ are very different beasts, but full-featured debuggers exist for both languages and many systems today are written combining them, so there's clearly a need there.

I don't see any fundamental reason why it shouldn't be possible to bring them together under one IDE. With a well-designed debugging platform it should be possible to integrate many other languages, even (why not) interpreted languages like Python. What am I missing?

Comment: Is your question why isn't there such a debugger? Or is your question would it be hard to write one?

Comment: I think it would be quite useless to have such debugger. If both implementations are solid in different languages and do their work as they should, and the cross talk is only through immutable states, predefined set of rules and constants, then the chance of bug is very low.However, if the cross implementation is too "hands on and touchy feely", then no debugger would help you, since it is poor design in a first place.

Comment: AFAIR  Borland Turbo Debugger is able to debug executable compiled with the Turbo Assebmler. To debug C or Pascal programs they should be created by Turbo C or Turbo Pascal correspondingly.

Comment: @TheLaw I think that's equivalent to arguing against integration testing: "If every subsystem is unit tested, there should be no need to test the integration."

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I guess both. I'm asking if there's a fundamental reason why there is no such debugging environment. Do people not see the benefit (like @TheLaw), is there no market for it (I doubt that), or is it simply too complex a problem, and if so why?

Comment: The [GNU Debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger) per Wikipedia *is a portable debugger that runs on many Unix-like systems and works for many programming languages, including Ada, C, C++, Objective-C, Free Pascal, Fortran, Java[1] and partially others.*

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks Elliot. Most IDEs can interface with it too. I'll try it out. If you write this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia describes the [GNU debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger) as

> a portable debugger that runs on many Unix-like systems and works for many programming languages, including Ada, C, C++, Objective-C, Free Pascal, Fortran, [Java](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Supported-Languages.html#Supported-Languages) and partially [others](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Summary.html#Summary).

Additionally, many UIs and IDEs on Unix-like systems can interface with gdb (the GNU Debugger), such as [ddd](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) (a visual debugger built on gdb) and [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/4682/) and [Code::Blocks](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Debugging_with_Code::Blocks) (and others).

Answer (score 0):

The visual studio debugger has this capability, it will step through native C++, C# and assembler.

It can be extended, which last time I looked looks plausible for JVM, python.